# Status code: Unauthorized when using https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/API and my own scripts

Tags: api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, unauthorized

Quickbooks API simply does not work for me. Using their own API exporer it wont even work (get internalserver errors and unauthorized errors. Basically I can only do things in https ://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer successfully but when doing it using their other API tool it fails with the mentioned errors. As well as my own scripts error out the same exact way.

Also note that I can call to anything using the API inside of my script to the domain of https: //appcenter.intuit.com/api but nothing to the domain of https: //qbo.intuit.com/qbo32 (note that the appcenter is a simple get request however and the other is a complex post request).

Example of what I do to duplicate:

- Goto https: //appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth and fill out
  consumer key and secret with my app info from
  https: //developer.intuit.com/Application/Manage
- Click request token using key and secret and it returns key and
  secret
- Authorize request Token button which then takes me through the popup
  which then I authorize access
- Now I have access token and secret and then i goto the api console
- Now at api console at https: //appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/API and
  i see my 4 keys included
- I run a test by doing a GET request to
  https: //appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/user/current with no params and
  it shows my user
- I then try and do a POST to something like
  https: //qbo.intuit.com/qbo32/resource/invoices/v2/169115718 and the
  URL params of PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=1 and then call API
- It returns "Status code: Unauthorized", and if I omit the URL params
  it then says "Status code: InternalServerError"

I have spend 2 days on this and have no solution using every available tool including calling support. Keep in mind also that this same situation and messages exists in my own code as well. This is just the easier to troubleshoot method because I assume if we fix this, then my code may work with similar changes.

PS: I added a space into the urls because this tool would not let me make them clickable for you

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that that base url is correct? Are you sure your realm ID is correct? Where did you get those values?

Comment: all the URLS provided above are from the API explorer so maybe the base URL is not correct, but I have not yet found anywhere that gives me explicit base url info. The realm ID is from the same location and I notice its actually our customer id so I assume it is correct.

Comment: Strike that, found the base url I am to use and its: <qbo:BaseURI>https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo32</qbo:BaseURI> which is exactly what I have been using. Also this new info came from calling https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/rest/user/v2/169115718 in the API

Comment: I appear to have self resolved. The issue with their API tool appears to have been the same type of bug with the method for which I make my http requests in PHP. While I have not been able to fix their API tool to work, I did switch over to using CURL and the POST method now work with no change to anything. So I am frustrated but its working for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Apiexplorer tool.

Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO

In apiexplorer, You don't need to configure any endpoints. You can trigger any endpoints using valid OAuth tokens.

If you pass paging attributes in POST body, Apiexplorer shows 401 error. Most probably it is a bug. To test paging related use cases, you can copy endpoint and credentials from apiexplorer and use those in some other restclients.

Ref - [Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid when adding anything to the request body on POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243789/unauthorized-oauth-token-signature-invalid-when-adding-anything-to-the-request)

Please let me know if it helps. If not, you can raise a support ticket from the following link.

Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/0010_submit_support_incidents

Thanks

Comment: Yea I have tried many regular rest clients and get the same outcome. This includes the API explorer and my own application. The issue is only when including anything in POST for filtering or paging. This is a serious hangup and I am sad.

Comment: In your application r u using devkit or directly calling the API-Endpoint ?Plz mention which language u r using.
Thanks

Comment: I am using PHP and so had to build my own. Calling right to API. Is there some special way I need to call to this API that is not documented in anything on the Intuit dev api doc?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use dev defined oauth code as mentioned here:
https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6024616

Comment: I am using PHP so I cannot.