# Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid when adding anything to the request body on POST

Tags: api, post, quickbooks

When doing any filters or any other option allowed in the request body per documents like this: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/in... (the quickbooks online API document) I always get the error "Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid" in my own application as well as the API tool located here: https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

Example of what I put in request body:
PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=20
or simply ResultsPerPage=20

I am not sure why this would also happen in the API Explorer even per instruction but it does. Without the ability to move the page marker and show more results as well as being able to filter, I will simply not be able to use the API as you can see.

Any ideas?

Comment: Found a similar issue reported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695065/quickbooks-online-querying-with-filter-returns-401-everytime and it has no answer from 5 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug in ApiExplorer. I tried with RestClient plugin of Mozilla browser. It worked fine.

- Method - post
- Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Paging filter - PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=1

Snapshot

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Anyway you can show me that same tools request header? It still get the same thing even in that same rest tool in chrome. If I put anything in the body it says "Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid"

Comment: Could it be account related in some way?

Comment: Please verify the dynamic base URL
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0100_calling_data_services/0010_getting_the_base_url#Getting_the_Base_URL_at_Runtime

Request Header -
1. Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. 4 tokens which I got from ApiExplorer

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone think that maybe the issue is account related or something else in the backend at intuit? I think maybe its that Intuit has us hitting an older version of the API while qbo1/ account is hitting a newer built one? This could explain why some people do not have this problem.